# Big data table MySQL query optimization

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization, bigdata

I'm trying to optimize my MySQL query to run more smoothly, but now I'm stuck.

I'm using this query:

```
SELECT
    sr.path,
    sr.keywordId,
    sr.rank
FROM
    serp_results sr
WHERE
    sr.domain = 971
    AND sr.searchEngine = 1
```

And it tries to get results from the table where it is approximately **544,003,737** rows. I recently added a compound index for columns **searchEngine,domain**, but it didn't work.

This is the table structure:

```
| Field             | Type                 | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
|-------------------|----------------------|------|-----|---------|----------------|
| id                | bigint(10) unsigned  | NO   | PRI |         | auto_increment |
| keywordId         | int(10) unsigned     | NO   | MUL |         |                |
| searchEngine      | tinyint(3) unsigned  | NO   | PRI |         |                |
| position          | smallint(5) unsigned | NO   |     |         |                |
| rank              | float unsigned       | NO   |     |         |                |
| path              | varchar(500)         | NO   |     |         |                |
| domain            | bigint(20) unsigned  | YES  | MUL |         |                |
| firstDomainResult | tinyint(1) unsigned  | NO   |     |         |                |
| added             | date                 | YES  | MUL |         |                |
```

+ indexes:

```
| index_name                         | index_algorithm | is_unique | column_name                        |   |
|------------------------------------|-----------------|-----------|------------------------------------|---|
| serp_results_searchEngine_domain   | BTREE           | FALSE     | searchEngine,domain                |   |
| serp_results_domain_index          | BTREE           | FALSE     | domain                             |   |
| serp_results_added_index           | BTREE           | FALSE     | added                              |   |
| keywordId_searchEngine_position    | BTREE           | TRUE      | keywordId,searchEngine,position    |   |
| domain_firstDomainResult_keywordId | BTREE           | FALSE     | domain,firstDomainResult,keywordId |   |
| PRIMARY                            | BTREE           | TRUE      | id,searchEngine                    |   |
```

**EDIT:** It does take around 60+ seconds for a larger number of domain records.

Comment: Please post the table structure + indexes as text in your question. Problem with images on other sites is they dissappear before the question does

Comment: How many rows are being returned?  You might simply have a date volume issue.

Comment: In this particular example, there are 662,733 rows returned.

Comment: @GordonLinoff What do you mean by "data volume issue"?

Comment: @DavidPivoňka . . . If you are returning 10,000,000 rows then that will take some time.

Comment: I'm creating a temporary table with these data and then using `WHERE sr.keywordId IN(1, 2, 3, 4, 5) -- Maximum of 200 IDs` on it

Comment: Wait!  I don't see `IN` in your query.  Nor do I see a `JOIN`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's why it takes a long time.  (I will intersperse some questions to help confirm my statements.)

- Your table is InnoDB.  (Yes?)
- Your RAM is much smaller than the table (How big, in GB, is the table?  How much RAM?  What is the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`.)
- The 662,733 rows are scattered around the table.  (Or is there some reason why those rows might be clustered chronologically?)
- You have a spinning HDD, or you have SSD drive(s).  (I don't think this matters for my discussion; but which do you have?)
- `PRIMARY KEY(id, searchEngine)` is very strange, given that `id` is `AUTO_INCREMENT`.  (Can you justify it?)
- Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`; it is more descriptive than `DESCRIBE`.
- Do you have other important queries?  (Sometimes speeding up one query will slow down others.  That is the direction I want to go.  Show the ones you don't want me to slow down.)
- Can `domain` be just `INT`?  (I am looking also at shrinking the table size.)

As to why more than 60 seconds...  A significant percentage of the 662,733 rows needed to be fetched from disk.

Get some of those questions answered; then I may have a concrete suggestion for speeding up the query.